# shifting elements from arraylist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a project and I stuck to this thing. I want to display alarms on the page in a html table only in three rows.For the moment I have three tables but I want to multiple table4,table5 table6, etc.

This is my code from the project:

```
public ArrayList myArr = new ArrayList();

public static string alarma_valoare { get; set; }
public static string alarma_denumire_punct { get; set; }
public static string alarma_timp  { get; set; }
public static string alarma_mesaj { get; set; }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PresSelect();
    TempSelect();
    DebSelect();
    DataDisplay();
}

public void PresSelect()
{

    string query = "String table1";

    dt = GetData(query);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            alarm_value = dt.Rows[i]["value"].ToString();
            alarm_n = dt.Rows[i]["value1"].ToString();
            alarma_date = dt.Rows[i]["value2"].ToString();
            alarma_text = dt.Rows[i]["value3"].ToString();



           if (float.Parse(alarm_value) > 11)
            {

                myAr.Add(float.Parse(alarm_value));
                myAr.Add(alarm_n.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_date.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_text.ToString());



            }
            else if (float.Parse(alarm_value) < 11)
            {

                myAr.Add(float.Parse(alarm_value));
                myAr.Add(alarm_n.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_date.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_text.ToString());
            }
         }
    }
}

public void TempSelect()
{

    string query = "string  table2";

    dt = GetData(query);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {

            alarm_value = dt.Rows[j]["value"].ToString();             
            alarm_n = dt.Rows[j]["value1"].ToString();
            alarma_date = dt.Rows[j]["value2"].ToString();
            alarma_text = dt.Rows[j]["value3"].ToString();

             if (float.Parse(alarm_value) > 22)
            {

                myAr.Add(float.Parse(alarm_value));
                myAr.Add(alarm_n.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_date.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_text.ToString());
            }
            else if (float.Parse(alarm_value) < 22)
           {
                myAr.Add(float.Parse(alarm_value));
                myAr.Add(alarm_n.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_date.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_text.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}

public void DebSelect()
{

    string query = "String table3";

    dt = GetData(query);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < dt.Rows.Count; y++)
        {


             alarm_n = dt.Rows[y]["value1"].ToString();
             alarma_date = dt.Rows[y]["value2"].ToString();
             alarma_text = dt.Rows[y]["value3"].ToString();

            if (float.Parse(alarm_value) >33)
            {

                    myAr.Add(float.Parse(alarm_value));
                    myAr.Add(alarm_n.ToString());
                    myAr.Add(alarma_date.ToString());
                    myAr.Add(alarma_text.ToString());
            }
            else if (float.Parse(alarm_value) < 33 )
            {

                myAr.Add(float.Parse(alarm_value));
                myAr.Add(alarm_n.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_date.ToString());
                myAr.Add(alarma_text.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}

public void DataDisplay()
{


    //in this function I want to display data in my html table

 }



private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);

            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
}
```

I put all value from those table in this array how look like this:

```
[0]  value - from table1
[1]  value1 - from table1
[2]  value2 - from table1
[3]  value3 - from table1

[4]  value - from table2
[5]  value1 - from table2
[6]  value2 - from table2
[7]  value3 - from table2

[8]  value - from table3
[9]  value1 - from table3
[10] value2 - from table3
[11] value3 - from table3
```

End I want to display in a html table like this:

```
Value/name                Date                           Message   
value/value1(T1)        value2(T1)                       value3(T1)
value/value1(T2)        value2(T2)                       value3(T2)
value/value1(T3)        value2(T3)                       value3(T3)
```

When in the database come a new value  for table3 my array I want to look like this:

```
 [0]  value - from table3
 [1]  value - from table3
 [2]  value - from table3
 [3]  value - from table3

 [4]  value - from table1
 [5]  value - from table1
 [6]  value - from table1
 [7]  value - from table1

 [8]  value - from table2
 [9]  value - from table2
 [10] value - from table2
 [11] value - from table2

 Value/name                Date                           Message   
 value/value1(T3)        value2(T3)                       value3(T3)
 value/value1(T1)        value2(T1)                       value3(T1)
 value/value1(T2)        value2(T2)                       value3(T2)
```

And a another value from table2

```
  [0]  value - from table2
  [1]  value - from table2
  [2]  value - from table2
  [3]  value - from table2

  [4]  value - from table3
  [5]  value - from table3
  [6]  value - from table3
  [7]  value - from table3

  [8]  value - from table1
  [9]  value - from table1
  [10] value - from table1
  [11] value - from table1

  Value/name                Date                           Message   
 value/value1(T2)        value2(T2)                       value3(T2)
 value/value1(T3)        value2(T3)                       value3(T3)
 value/value1(T1)        value2(T1)                       value3(T1)
```

I want to move elements in myArrraylist and display in the html table this is want I want to do in this moment for three table from my database but in the future I have multiple table.

Sorry for my bad english, if don't understand I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a Queue.

Let me explain.  If you have a Queue (you can do some check to always have 12 elements) and you start to Enqueue values, you will have something like this:

```
  [11]  value - from table3
  [10]  value - from table3
  [9]  value - from table3
  [8]  value - from table3

  [7]  value - from table2
  [6]  value - from table2
  [5]  value - from table2
  [4]  value - from table2

  [3]  value - from table1
  [2]  value - from table1
  [1] value - from table1
  [0] value - from table1
//First element
```

Then if you get a new value:

Use Dequeue() 4 times and you wil lhave this:

```
  [7]  value - from table3
  [6]  value - from table3
  [5]  value - from table3
  [4]  value - from table3

  [3]  value - from table2
  [2]  value - from table2
  [1]  value - from table2
  [0]  value - from table2
//First element
```

And then use Enqueue() with the four new values, and you will have something like this:

```
  [11]  value - from table4
  [10]  value - from table4
  [9]  value - from table4
  [8]  value - from table4

  [7]  value - from table3
  [6]  value - from table3
  [5]  value - from table3
  [4]  value - from table3

  [3]  value - from table2
  [2]  value - from table2
  [1] value - from table2
  [0] value - from table2
    //First element
```

Get it? ;) 
I think that could be a solution for your problem!

Here the idea:

```
Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();

            queue.Enqueue("prueba1");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba2");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba3");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba4");

            queue.Enqueue("prueba5");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba6");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba7");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba8");

            queue.Enqueue("prueba9");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba10");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba11");
            queue.Enqueue("prueba12");

            if (queue.Count == 12)
            {
                queue.Dequeue();
                queue.Dequeue();
                queue.Dequeue();
                queue.Dequeue();
                queue.Enqueue("prueba13");
                queue.Enqueue("prueba14");
                queue.Enqueue("prueba15");
                queue.Enqueue("prueba16");
            }
```

Comment: Maybe if you post a example(an ideea) for my problem using Queue and Dequeue to understand this concept.

Comment: I think that it´s easy. Create the Queue. Then, in the rows when you are actually "Adding" elements to your list, Check if your Queue is alreaady with 12 elements, and if it is, then first Dequeue() four elements, and Enqueue() the new ones, if is not full and stil lhave space, then onle Enqueue the new elements.

Comment: I search on the google and i understant something of this concept. By now the problem is I don't now how to display this thing in my html table.
Sorry for my newbie questions but I'm not a programmer, but I have to finish this project

Comment: Sorry, but I don´t know how to help you with the web part. I am not a web developer. So sorry, but in this question, I only can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use ArrayList for this. Create a class to hold your data and provide it meaningful property names. Your could then change your GetData method to provide a collection of these classes that you can use in your presentation logic to populate your HTML table.

Maybe something like the following

```
class AlarmData {

    public float AlarmValue { get; set; }
    public string AlarmN { get; set; }
    public string AlarmDate { get; set; } // Could even be of type DateTime
    public string AlarmText { get; set; }

}
```

In your `DebSelect`, `TempSelect` and `PresSelect` methods, you have lots of repeated code. Maybe move a lot of that to your GetData method and rather than populating the arraylist create a collection of `AlarmData` objects and return those.

Then your `DebSelect`, `TempSelect` and `PresSelect` methods can simply do your conditional logic on the data returned.

For your `DataDisplay` method I'd investigate the [ASP.NET Repeater Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build your ASP.NET table or DIVS or whatever method you choose to layout the content. If you really want to you can look at data binding with your custom business object (`AlarmData`) to help simplify things further.

This is a considerable deviation from your original example, but it is probably a worthwhile one I'd suggest.